# Run Google App Scripts client side

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I don't know if this is a dumb question, but can I load the Cloud saved scripts (that I program using the Script Editor in Google Docs) onto the client when opening the sheet, so that the code doesn't run on a Google server but on my computer instead? 
I should mention I'm very new to this.

Comment: Non of the Apps Script services (Classes, properties) can run client side except for `google.script.run.myFunction()` and `google.script.host`  Anything with `google.script` in front of it.  So, if you have written some code in a `.gs` script file, and it has Apps Script services in it, it won't run in a browser.  The generic JavaScript will run in the browser.  The generic JavaScript is the same in both browser and client (for the most part).  So, `SpreadsheetApp`, `DriveApp`, `FormApp`, `Logger`, `CalendarApp`, `Utilities`, etc will NOT run in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Some app commands let you run a script in the client side indirectly.
For example, if you create a sidebar, the html code you inject in the sidebar is run on the client and it can contain a script.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars

Answer (score 0):

No.

However, if you want to interact with Google services from the client side, you could use the execution API. Details here: [GAS-execution-API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/)